# Unable to install drivers to get adb working on all my android devices

Tags: android

I recently got an issue with my android devices. I currently have  a nexus one, nexus 4 and a mt65xx android phone.

Adb was working fine on my mt65xx previously. however i encounted error installing my nexus 4 adb so i unisntalled all the android drivers. After that, i'm no longer able to install back the drivers for any of my phone i listed above.

I'm very sure i did the right way of installation through the device manager.

The directly for the usb driver is as following C:\Users\user-Home\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver . I tried it for my nexus one and nexus 4 but when i browse to the location and press next , it gave me the error "windows could not find driver software for your device".

I've also tried to force install by clicking "let me pick from a list of device" and i choosed have disk. it did get installed sucesfully however when i run adb devices, it did not show my android device... it is working fine on my another pc though

This is very fruastrating, i have been trying to solve this issue  for around 2-3 days. How can it be solve?

Comment: silly question, but have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: did you check your Device manager when you connect your device? is it a yellow mark next to your device name?

Comment: yes it is a yellow mark next to my device... 

I did try restarting my phone, my com  no solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Samsung Kies or you have to install your device drivers manually:

```
Device Manaager -> yourDevice -> UpdateDriverSoftware -> Browse My Computer ... -> Let Me Pick From a List -> Samsung Android ADB InterFace
```

Comment: will samsung kies help my nexus device?

Comment: i've tried installing it manually it did work but i am unable to see it from my adb when i type adb devices

Comment: yes ,i'm working on Nexus 7 and it's Drivers provided by Samsung so Samsung Kies should help you , but otherwise sometimes i update the drivers manually from the List and it absolutely works!

Comment: let me try install kies. 

I did manually update from the list before it did get installed but not recognised when i type adb devices

Comment: maybe restarting adb help finding the device but in my case after installing Samsung adb Interface , the eclipse find the devices Automtically , if the the yellow mark removed , its a good sign! :)

Comment: i tried restarting adb and all shit, still not working. yes yellow mark is removed when i try to manually install from device manager.

Comment: at least give me a up vote if you guys can't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

install your device drivers manually:
Device Manager -> yourDevice -> UpdateDriverSoftware -> Browse My Computer ... -> Let Me Pick From a List -> select "show all devices" - > click next -> install from disk -> click browsering -> select your %Android SDK directory%\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf

follow the next tips and ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction :

1 . reinstall usb driver.

2 . Install [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992345) driver.

3 Enable "USB Debugging" in your phone.

4 . Try again.

---

Now should be ok.

Bye,

Comment: did not work. I 'm very sure this is the same as what i tried to install from google sdk....

Comment: do you have enabled "USB Debugging" in Developer Settings in your phone ?

Comment: yes, did you even read my question? everything work well on my another pc.

Comment: reinstall sdk - this is last help desk

Comment: how do you even re-install sdk? isn't sdk just a folder?

Comment: the answer is not even valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue like yours, eventually I decided to make a tool, that should fix the for any Android device, you just have to

1. connect the phone in USB Debugging mode to PC and run the tool.

It will detect the install the drivers specific to your phone

Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows)